# Matching a carriage return

Tags: javascript

The carriage return isn't matched by the regex or the hardcoded symbol:

```
if (!senArray[i].indexOf(/\r/) || !senArray[i].indexOf('↵'))
    continue;
```

The array content: `senArray = ["↵"]`

How can I match it so that the current iteration skips ?

Comment: First, please post the code - not an image.  Second, you should check for newline (\n)  as well as carriage return (\r), and forget the string search for an arrow.

Comment: Why didn't you post this as text? Also, why do you think a unicode character representing an arrow would actually match a newline?

Comment: Also, indexOf will return index (number), if found, and -1 if substring is not found...

Comment: it returns truthy when found, falsey when not found, sinisake.

Comment: I wouldn't say that (i might be wrong), includes() returns true or false. Check this, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/e99zdzbL/1/

Comment: It returns -1 if not found otherwise it will return index position of the first occurrence.

Comment: @archer: I made a picture to show both code and actual array content as displayed by inspector

Comment: Images disappear - you should not use them in questions when you don't need to.

Comment: I edited accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

indexOf does not accept a regular expression (as you supplied) whereas the `\n` would work just fine.

```js
x=[`
`]
console.log(x.indexOf('\n')) //.. 0
```